# CSRF Symfony2 Always invalid token

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm getting mad with this. On my local environment all my forms work perfectly.

In my prod environment my forms break, and Symfony2 throws me this error:

> Invalid CSRF token. send the form again

Okay, I was googling and found a lot of solutions, but nothing works.

I'm manually printing the `{{ form_row(form._token) }}` on each form but the error still happens.

On my parameters.yml I set the domain manually too.

What I must to do?

In all my forms I do the handleRequest():

```
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
```

Example of form:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        {{ form_start(form, { 'style': 'horizontal', 'attr': {'autocomplete': 'off'} }) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }} 
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>{{ 'profile.edit.socialNetworks'|trans({}, 'user') }}</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        {{ form_row(form.twitter) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.youtube) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.website, { 'help_text': 'profile.edit.field.help.website'|trans({}, 'user') }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h4>{{ 'profile.edit.myGameaccounts'|trans({}, 'user') }}</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form_label(form.userSteamTrade) }}
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                {{ form_widget(form.userSteamTrade) }}
                                <span class="help-block"><a href="#" id="steamTrade">{{ 'profile.edit.field.help.steamTradeLink'|trans({}, 'user') }}</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{ form_row(form.userSteam) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.userLol, { 'label': 'profile.edit.field.lolSum'|trans({}, 'user') }) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.userXbox) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.userPs4) }}
                        {{ form_row(form.userBattlenet, { 'help_text': 'profile.edit.field.help.bnet'|trans({}, 'user') }) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h4>{{ 'profile.edit.save'|trans({}, 'user') }}</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            {{ form_row(form.current_password, { 'help_text': 'profile.edit.field.help.password'|trans({}, 'user') }) }}
                            {{ form_row(form.actions) }}
                            {{ form_row(form._token) }}
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

### Symfony version: 2.7

Comment: Are you logged in on the website? It looks like the session is invalidated, you should check how much time the session is valid. Check the [`session`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#session) parameters.

Comment: And make sure whatever directory is storing the sessions is writable.

Comment: change to `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}`

Comment: Yes @A.L im logged in on my website.

My directory to store sessions is app/sessions and yes, it have 775 permisisons.

I changed to form_widget and nothing... :(

Comment: which Symfony2 version do you use? could you please edit question and add source of your template with form.

Comment: Yes, im using Symfony 2.7

Comment: I don't see any problems in your code. your code worked on local dev environment, maybe the case in prod environment settings. check session settings on your prod server, maybe session storage is not writable, in debian like systems usually it is /var/lib/php5

Comment: At this point I would switch to development mode on your production server and see if anything jumps out.

Comment: I think it may be related to Symfony2 configuration. The production environment is in a subdomain, and I have assigned to the variable domain the value of the subdomain in which is running Symfony2. If I change that value the web does not work. Is there any method by which Symfony is able to function in the parent domain and any subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Was a problem with `domain` variable inside parameters.yml

I set `domain` to the default value `~` and it works.

parameters.yml before:

```
domain: subdomain.domain.net
```

parameters.yml after:

```
domain: ~
forceDomain: subdomain.domain.net # This var is mine not default by Symfony2 to force some routes to execute just on this subdomain
```

Thanks a lot guys! U rocks!